# Failed to open stream error occurring with Japanese character

Tags: php

I am using **`common.inc`** file in PHP. During using, it occurred errors. The error is :

> failed to open stream: ､ｽ､ﾎ､隍ｦ､ﾊ･ﾕ･｡･､･�茹ﾇ･｣･�ｯ･ﾈ･熙ﾏ､｢､熙ﾞ､ｻ､�

I edited  many time in file, but nothing changed. It has many functions but that function only can't work. Other function can work. I set `require_once()`. Directory also corrected. Now, I don't know how to solve because any testing can't do. The same error only showing. I can't use `echo`, `print` etc. I have no idea now.

Please help me kindly.

Answer (score 0):

It look like is something issue of file Encoding issue.
You can try to save your ini file to utf-8 and try it again.